# Erro em ASP NET (DbContextService)

Tags: .net, asp.net

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou com esse erro quando tento acessar um web forms no projeto. Este erro apenas acontece quando estou utilizando um servidor do IIS, pois no IIS local (do Visual Studio) não é mostrado nenhum erro, e a página funciona perfeitamente.

Rastreamento de pilha:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

DBContext:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

PessoaRepository:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

foCadUsuario.aspx

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Amigo, tu poderias compartilhar o código (um exemplo mínimo) que reproduz o problema, bem como as configurações necessárias?

Comment: Pronto. Adicionei algumas imagens das linhas exatas que são mostradas no Rastreamento de Pilha. @LeonardoAlvesMachado